# Is It Possible to Override an Expected Exception in JUnit?

Tags: java, exception, testing, junit, mockito

I recently found out that JUnit > 4.10 allows the usage of `@Rule` and `ExpectedException`. Since I'm not big on duplicating code I tried the following. For a better understanding I scaled it down from several tests to just these two. The `MockitoJUnitRunner` is intentional although it's not used in the small scaled example.

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
  <!-- Test dependencies -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.19</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

TestBase

```
 @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class TestBase {
   /** JUnit > 4.10 allows expected exception handling like this */
   @Rule
   public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

   @Before
   public void setup() {
     this.expectBadParam();
   }

   protected void expectBadParam() {
     this.exception.expect(NullPointerException.class);
   }
 }
```

The problem is that the following test is not working as I would expect it to. What I'm trying is by default expect an exception type and in some cases run a normal JUnit test. I can't reset the expected exception once it's set.

```
 public class ExpectedExceptionTest extends TestBase {
   @Test
   public void error() {
     throw new NullPointerException();
   }

   @Test
   public void success() {
     this.exception = ExpectedException.none();
     // this should be a success
   }
 }
```

I already found a different solution by duplicating the expectBadParam method in each method I expect an exception as well as overriding the `@Before` annotation in the test class. However I'm hoping someone can help me understand why this is not working?

Comment: You should override the setup instead, or just not inherit `TestBase`

Comment: How does overriding the setup (which I did my real implementation) help when I want to avoid code duplication? e.g. 45 tests are supposed to throw a bad param exception whereas 4 tests are supposed to run with a normal success. 
The same goes for the suggestion not to inherit from `TestBase`. There are multiple tests that are using that super class. I sized the example down for a better comprehension. 
It still eludes me why I can't use ExpectedException from JUnit to reset to no expected exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's not working as you expect (no pun intended) is related to how `TestRule`s work with JUnit.

Effectively what happens is that the test framework inspects the test case for `TestRule` instances, and then calls the `TestRule.apply()` method on each on in turn. This method takes a `Statement` object and returns a `Statement()`. Your test case object is initially wrapped in a Statement, given to the first TestRule, which returns a **brand new** `Statement` wrapping the original `Statement`. So, basically, the TestRule is being given the opportunity to **adapt** the original TestCase, generally adding new functionality. Once the framework has gone through all the TestRule instances it calls the `Statement.evaluate()` method, like it would do for any 'standard' test case it builds up which doesn't have any TestRules attached to it.

The key thing here is that all the interaction between the framework and the `TestRule` instances happens at test case construction time. Once the test case has been built up, the fields containing the rules are no longer queried or directly interacted with by the test framework. Their main purpose afterwards is for tests to interact with the mutable state contained within the rules. So, if you change the instance field as you do in your test case `success()` you'll have absolutely no effect on the outcome of the rules, because the rule expecting an `IllegalArgumentException` has already been applied to the test case.

There's a 'typical' shape to a `TestRule` implementation. They look like this...

```
public void apply(Statement base, Description description) {
    return new Statement() {
        public void evaluate( ) {
            // some initialisation
            try {
                base.evaluate();
            } finally {
                // some tidy up here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the TestRule gets an opportunity to run some code **after** the test case has completed. This is how ExpectedException works (although it has a 'catch Exception(e)' block also). During the course of the test you can call methods on the rule instance which builds up state within the TestRule object which is then used when the finally block is called. So, when you call 'exception.expect(IllegalArgumentException.class)`, the test rule stores a matcher in a list and basically matches caught exceptions using that matcher and any others you may have set up. When you reset the instance field in your test case all that state in the original instance is still there and so the test still fails.

To do what you want to do you need a means of resetting the internal state of the `ExpectedException` instance. Unfortunately, there are no methods on the `ExpectedException` class which allow you to remove expectations which have been added. It's only really possible to add expectations. And, to be honest, this is for a good reason - your tests should be logically grouped, with finer grained details being added the closer you get to the test case. The act of 'resetting' expectations is an act of removing rather than adding a detail and so suggests that your tests are not logically grouped well enough. It creates maintainability difficulties if some part of a test suite adds some expectations and another part removes some / all of them.

You have 2 options if you want to use ExpectedException here. The first is to split your test class, or test base class, in two. One suite should be for tests which expect the IllegalArgumentException and another for ones which don't or which have some kind of alternative exception they expect. The second is to accept the duplication inherent in having 44 tests which have to explicitly declare they expect an exception and only 4 tests which don't.

It's possible you may be able to achieve what you want with JUnit `Theories` in some way, although that would depend very much on how your test cases work.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment. The detailed explanation helped me understand why for example it was possible for me to add further exceptions but not to change the instance. Also `Theories` looks promising for my next tests :D It's a similiar concept I already have in place with [Parametrized JUnit](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to Override the setup method,

You could also do it manually:

```
@Test
public void success() {
    try{
        ... all your code
    } catch (Exception e){
        // check your nested clauses
        if(e.getCause() instanceof ExpectedException){
            // pass
        } else {
            Assert.fail("unexpected exception");
        }
    }
```

Please find bellow interesting links to learn more about :

- [testing-custom-exceptions-w-junits](http://www.ensor.cc/2012/09/testing-custom-exceptions-w-junits.html)
- [Code showing how to test a custom exception by using a Hamcrest
  Matcher](https://github.com/mike-ensor/custom-exception-testing)

Good luck :)

Comment: I'm confused here. I already know that your solution is viable with older JUnit versions. Also there is `expected` value in the `@Test` annotation [reference](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-2-expected-exception-test/) that in my opinion is better than your solution. How does your example answer my question on how to use `ExpectedException` from JUnit?